# Face Recognition. Уменьшение ложных распознаваний

Tags: python, linux, функции, opencv, видео

Всем привет. Решаю задачу по распознаванию лиц. За основу  взял библиотеку Face_Recognition и приложенный к ней код. Суть задачи заключается в том, что мне нужно распознать человека(или несколько человек) проходящих мимо камеры и записать время его прохождения для последующего формирования статистики. В процессе эксплуатации этого инструмента выявил следующую проблему: если человек проходит мимо камеры(без остановки и не обязательно смотря в саму камеру), то большая часть распознаваний истинная, но при этом присутствует ложная составляющая. Обычно за секунду успевает сделать 12-15 записей(распознаваний), из которых 3-5 могут быть ложными. Количество человек в рамках данной задачи не большое ~20 человек, но в дальнейшем есть планы увеличить эту базу на несколько порядков. Пробовал изменить параметр tolerance от 0.6 до 0.8 с шагом 0.05, но особого изменения в результате не было. Хотел бы узнать кто-нибудь пробовал решить эту проблему на уровне применения встроенных функций библиотеке Face_Recognition.

upd под ложным распознаванием имеется ввиду ошибка классификации для одного человека.

Comment: Что в вашем контексте означает "ложное срабатывание"? Распознает объект но с ошибкой классификации? Вообще не распознает объект?  Приведенные цифры (12-15 записей(распознаваний) в секунду) это для каждого объекта в кадре (если их несколько) или это в траектории отслеживания одного конкретного объекта?

Comment: Вы верно, определили термин ложного распознавание. Т.е. проходит мимо Саша, и алгоритм за секунду может выдать 7 раз - Саша, 1 - Маша, 1- Петя,  и т.д.  Либо наоборот, проходит мимо камеры человек не из базы, а камера вместно Unknown выдаёт любого другого человека из списка. 12-15 записей для траектории одного конкретного объекта

Comment: только режим "как на паспорт" спасёт ваш регистратор, вы же убедились уже, что наклоны, повороты головы не дают результата, давая ложь. почему здесь спрашиваете? face_recognition - это 2D. ищите другие реализованные алгоритмы.

Comment: Ну можно что-то мутить в сторону выявления и отсева аномалий. Если у вас идет  7раз -  Саша, 1раз Маша, потом 3 раза снова Саша, 1 раз Петя и снова 4 раза Саша, то в общем понятно,  (если это видеоряд,  особенно с достаточно высокой частотой получения изображений) что и Маша и Петя это ошибка распознавания и на самом деле все это Саша. А дальше играться с этим, выявлять вот такие "аномалии", исключать их -  тут уж ваше творчество и умение мыслить, а не форумные подсказки помогут.

Comment: а модель как строили по нормальной фотке или по шакалистой в полоборота??